# Tool(preferably IntelliJ plugin) that shows local source code is outdated

Tags: intellij-idea, bitbucket

Is anyone aware of or uses any IntelliJ plugin that indicates if local source code is updated on repo, in other words the local source code is not up-to-date anymore?

If there is no such tool, maybe Bitbucket has such functionality or any other tool exists for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is a VCS integration in IntelliJ.
If you have it enabled (check Preferences | Version Control and see whether your repository is listed there).
If so, then please check Explicitly check for incoming commits on remotes under [Preferences | Version Control | Git](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-version-control-git.html)

In the right bottom corner you can see branch name, if you click on it you will get a [Branches popup](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manage-branches.html) and if the feature that was mentioned above is enabled, then you will see blue and green arrows which indicate incoming/outgoing changes.